# Ng test issue: Cannot find type definition file for '@angular/localize'

Tags: angular, angular14, angular15, angular16, angular17

upgrading from angular 14 to 17 I encountered issue with `ng test`. It is not working anymore.

Error:

```
PS C:\ForAngular17\src\ng\cat-ng> ng test
One or more browsers which are configured in the project's Browserslist configuration will be ignored as ES5 output is not supported by the Angular CLI.
Ignored browsers: ie 11, ie 10, ie 9, kaios 2.5, op_mini all
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
##teamcity[blockOpened name='JavaScript Unit Tests' flowId='']

Error: error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@angular/localize'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point of type library '@angular/localize' specified in compilerOptions



    12 03 2024 09:26:26.230:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.3 server started at http://localhost:9876/
    12 03 2024 09:26:26.232:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox with concurrency unlimited
    12 03 2024 09:26:26.233:ERROR [karma-server]: Error: Found 1 load error
        at Server.<anonymous> (C:\ForAngular17\src\ng\cat-ng\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:243:26)
        at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:631:28)
        at Server.emit (node:events:529:35)
        at emitListeningNT (node:net:1851:10)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
```

tsconfig.spec.json code:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "@angular/localize"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

package.json code

```
    {
  "name": "cat-ng",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --configuration production",
    "build-azure": "ng build --azure",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-community/angular": "^28.0.0",
    "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model": "^28.0.2",
    "@ag-grid-community/core": "^28.0.2",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard": "^28.0.2",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/column-tool-panel": "^28.0.2",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/excel-export": "^28.0.2",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/menu": "^28.0.2",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/range-selection": "^28.0.2",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model": "^28.0.2",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/set-filter": "^28.0.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^17.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^17.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^17.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.2.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^17.2.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^17.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^17.2.4",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^3.0.13",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.10.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.21",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.8.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngrx/data": "^17.1.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^17.1.1",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^17.1.1",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^17.1.1",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^17.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^17.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^17.1.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^17.2.3",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "bignumber.js": "^9.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "bootstrap-scss": "^5.3.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "date-input-polyfill": "^2.14.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fortawesome": "^0.0.1-security",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^2.1.3",
    "mathjs": "^10.6.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "ng-click-outside2": "^14.0.1",
    "ng-sidebar": "^8.1.1",
    "ngx-angular-query-builder": "^17.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^18.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "subsink": "^1.0.1",
    "tether": "^1.4.7",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^5.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^17.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.4",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/node": "^10.14.14",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-teamcity-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^1.19.0",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "5.3.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

What is the possible here? Thank you!

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: You should remove screenshot.

Comment: Your `tsconfig.spec.json`  in `"compilerOptions"` in `"types"` array must include  `"@angular/localize"`

Comment: @Ricudo, yes. it already there. updated my post to include it.

Comment: I've just added it to my project with angular 17 and adding types solved the problem. What about compatibility. Have you updated angular/localize karma and jasmine to the lates versions too? here is my related dev dependencies:`"@angular/localize": "^17.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",`

Comment: @Ricudo, yes. it's updated. also updated post, attached package.json code. Thanks

Comment: hm, I don't see `@angular/localize` in your dev dependencies, I think it might be problem for ng test.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found the fix for this or not, but I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by simply adding

```
/// <reference types="@angular/localize" />
```

to the top of my `/src/test.ts` file, just like the `/src/main.ts` has. Seems that older versions of angular used the `test.ts` file by default, though, installing a new Angular 17 app does not have this `test.ts` file and it all seems to be pre-configured.

Doing some deeper research as to why this fixed it and if we can now remove the `test.ts` file safely since Angular 17 no longer comes with it by default.

Hope this helps!